# Launching an Mac App with Objective-C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, launching-application

When launching Path Finder app with command line, I use `open -a Path Finder.app /Users/`.
Based on this idea, I use the following code to launch Path Finder.

Can I have launch app without using `open` command line?

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-a", @"Path Finder.app", @"/Users/", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if(![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Path Finder"])
    NSLog(@"Path Finder failed to launch");
```

With Parameters:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[workspace fullPathForApplication:@"Path Finder"]];
//Handle url==nil
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Argument1", @"Argument2", nil];
[workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:0 configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arguments forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:&error];
//Handle error
```

You could also use NSTask to pass arguments:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:@"Path Finder"]]];
[task setLaunchPath:[bundle executablePath]];
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Argument1", @"Argument2", nil];
[task setArguments:arguments];
[task launch];
```

Comment: You will need to use launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error: to do that. I will add an example using that to my post.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but in terms of brevity, my answer (using openFile: withApplication:) seems better (easier to understand and shorter).

Comment: How do I access the configuration dictionary in the opened app?

Comment: @rocky You cannot directly access the dictionary, but the arguments stored in the dictionary will be passed as command line arguments, so you can use `argc` and `argv` in your main function.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw which one will be fast?

Answer (score 3):

Based on yuji's answer in [different posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048777/how-to-quit-itself-in-objective-c-application/5048824#5048824), [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the tool to use, and I could get the same result with only two lines of code.

The `openFile` can be used for passing the parameter to `Path Finder`, which is normally the directory, not a file. However, it works fine.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:string2 withApplication:@"Path Finder"];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
```

Comment: this will not work it the _parameter_ is not a file but a **parameter** of the application