# How to quit itself in Objective-C application?

Tags: objective-c, protocol-handler

I have a URLHandler that launches some application, the main code is as follows.

```
@implementation URLHandlerCommand

- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    NSString *urlString = [self directParameter];

    NSLog(@"url :=: %@", urlString);

    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];

    NSArray *arguments;
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-a", @"Path Finder.app", urlString, nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    return nil;
}
```

As the goal of this routine is to launch another application, I'd like to make this URLHandler quit after launching an App. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. You don't have to launch `open` using `NSTask`... `open` just calls into [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), some of whose functionality is directly available from [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. To quit, you just call `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil]`. See [`NSApplication` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems that `exit(0)` just works fine.

Comment: I recommend against `exit(0)`. Cocoa might want to do some cleaning up before quitting. I'm not sure if Cocoa registers these cleaning up functions with `atexit`, so I suggest you to call `-[NSApplication terminate:]`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here: [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application) however you should also take a look at August's answer. Although it's not the accepted answer, it has been voted higher and it also follows Apple's set standards since Apple advises against force quitting iPhone applications.

Comment: Actually, it's a Mac app, not an iPhone app.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry for making an assumption.