# How to kill application in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, monomac

How can i kill the application in xamarin.mac I cant find `this.dispose` or `Application.Exit` in xamarinMac So How can I kill the application in Xamarin Mac

Answer (score 11):

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(this)
```

or from static methods

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(NSApplication.SharedApplication);
```

Comment: This is not telling NSApplication.Run to stop for me. Neither this nor the Stop method

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSApplication.Terminate`.

http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Terminate

according to

[How to quit itself in Objective-C application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048777/how-to-quit-itself-in-objective-c-application)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just use Quit in the application class itself.  So as part of the application, I created a page and when that page closed, I called quit.  Here is my example:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    else
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    MainPage.Disappearing += MainPage_Disappearing;
}
void MainPage_Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Quit();
}
```