# What's Python's os.system() equivalent to cocoa/Objective-C?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, shell, command

I'd like to run some terminal command within my Mac program. 
For example, I normally use `mate abc.txt` or `python abc.py` from my shell to open Text Mate or running python script.

How can I do the same thing with Cocoa/Objective-C?

I thought about [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa), but I prefer just running in one line.

For example, when users enter "python abc.py", I just run the command as if it's in the Terminal.app. Python's equivalent command is `os.system()`.

[image: inputItem] <-- inputItem TextField

```
NSString* item = [inputItem stringValue];
[NSRuncommandLikeShell item]; <-- ????
```

The environment variables should be retained so that I don't need to run '/usr/bin/python'.

### EDIT

I can use `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` file for setup path environment. Or, I also could use [this utility](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/environmentvariablepreferencepane.html) for GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.  If you don't like all of the setup that goes in to this, you can create an `NSTask` category that does it for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? And with this method, can I have all the environment variables from bash .profile and .bashrc?

Comment: Yes. `NSTask` is certainly the way to go. Try to avoid `system()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C runtime `system()` call.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system([item UTF8String]);
```

Comment: It seems to work, but the shell PATH is lost to get this error : `e: command not found`

Comment: Try to avoid running `system()` calls in your code. They are localized to their own sessions (calling `system("cd ~/Desktop")` doesn't carry the current working directory to the next `system()` call), and are less safe than using `NSTask`. If I remember correctly, they're also pretty buggy, and prone to security hacks.