# Search for application in /Application folder first

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, nsworkspace

i'm searching for a way to open my other application with parameters and found a [very good post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa), but on my developer machine I have like 10 test/brach/release versions of my application and only one current stable version in /Application folder.

Both this code:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[workspace fullPathForApplication:@"My Application"]];
NSURL *url = [workspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"it.my_company.my_application"];
```

points to the wrong test/branch/release version. How do I find the URL of my application in /Application folder or at least URL at same level as my current running application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i'v came out to use:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

NSString *appPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
appPath = [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.app"];

if (not [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appPath])
    appPath = @"/Applications/MyApp.app";

if (not [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appPath])
    appPath = [workspace fullPathForApplication:@"MyApp"];

if (not [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appPath]) {
    return NO;
}
else {
    // found it in some place, now can launch.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `NSTask` messages: [`setLaunchPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`launchedTaskWithLaunchPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to supply an explicit path to your other application.

Something like:

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/Applications/My Application.app/Contents/MacOS/My Application" arguments:args];
```

Comment: I'v considered it, but it's a manual path writing... I was looking for altering the path search order.