# Cocoa code for launching an app with parameters

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want a Cocoa equivalent of the command line tool `open(1)`, especially for the usage in this form:

```
open -a <SomeApplication> <SomeFile> --args <Arg1> <Arg2> ...
```

Take QuickTime as an example. The following command line will open a file using QuickTime, and the arguments can control if QuickTime plays the file on startup.

```
open -a "QuickTime Player" a.mp4 --args -MGPlayMovieOnOpen 0 # or 1
```

I have read [Launching an Mac App with Objective-C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa). [prosseek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048968/711135), which I think is equivalent to `open -a <App> <File>`, works well when I do not specify any argument. [ughoavgfhw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048975/711135), which I think is equivalent to `open -a <App> --args <Arg1> <Arg2> ...`, works well when I do not specify any file to open. But neither can specify a filename and arguments at the same time.

I have also tried to append the filename to the argument list, which is the common way used by unix programs. It seems that some applications can accept it, but some cannot. QuickTime prompts an error saying it cannot open the file. I am using the following code.

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[workspace fullPathForApplication:@"QuickTime Player"]];
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-MGPlayMovieOnOpen", @"0", @"a.mp4", nil];
[workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:0 configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arguments forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:nil];
// open -a "QuickTime Player" --args -MGPlayMovieOnOpen 0 a.mp4
```

It seems that the mechanism in opening files differs from usual arguments. Can anyone explain the internals of `open(1)`, or just give me a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Also, can you share your code you tried when using the launchApplicationAtURL that didn't work?

Comment: Also, can you supply a valid example (works with open) where you pass filename and args?

Comment: @bryanmac I have added the code and an example using open.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to pipe the output of the task so you know the results. "a.mp4" needs to be the full path to the file.

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-a", @"QuickTime Player", @"--args", @"a.mp4", nil];
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments:args];

[task launch];
```

Comment: Yes, using `NSTask` to open `open(1)` will always work. I just wonder what is the method used by `open(1)`.

Comment: I plugged this code into an app and gave it the full path of an mp4 from itunes and it worked. Can you try some other content?

Comment: Well, I mean, I am curious about how `/usr/bin/open` is written, what classes and functions it uses, but not about how to use this tool.

Comment: @Pink Not sure of open's internals. But your original problem was playing a Quicktime movie from a Cocoa app. If this wasn't a solution then what sort of problem are you trying to solve?