# How to run mac application by script (.sh file)?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new in mac development. I have one problem. I made framework for Aperture that store images on particular place with some other information like username, password, no. of images and ftp server name etc. Then my another application start automatically, that application upload images on ftp server. My problem is how to start uploader application automatically. I think i can use script file and call this script file to first application. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: You want to start an application automatically when **what** occurs?

Comment: yes trojanfoe. End of one application, start automatically second application.

Comment: first_command.sh && second_command.sh in the second write `open -a "Mac application"`

Comment: Thanks Carlo. but i m new so plz explain your answer.

Comment: I think you need to use `NSTask` or similar to start an app from your framework.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe. How to do this? Please explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks trojanfoe and Parag Bafna. My solution is...

```
   NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]  fullPathForApplication:@"Path Finder"]]];
  [task setLaunchPath:[bundle executablePath]];
   NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Argument1", @"Argument2", nil];
   [task setArguments:arguments];
  [task launch];
```

I solve my problem. Thanks to all.

Comment: @ trojanfoe .. Why? If i am reason then sorry.

Comment: Well you basically used Parag Bafna's answer (from a comment I originally posted) so his answer should be accepted.  It's not reasonable to post your own answer and accept it using bits of answers provided by others, otherwise where is the motivation to answer at all?  You also appear a bit stingy with your upvotes...

Comment: No i used other link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa .

Answer (score 2):

You can use open command with -a option

```
open -a appName  


NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-a",@"appName",nil]];
[task launch];
[task release];
```

Comment: Thanks Parag Bafna. what is real path of application in this line          [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"]?

Comment: In appName , give full path or application name

Comment: i give full path like as  [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-a",@"/Applications/Uploader.app",nil]], but its not launch. How to launch application? Please help ..

Comment: Open terminal and run ls /Applications/Uploader.app, post output of that command.

Comment: @ Parag Bafna, I give this command on terminal "open /Applications/PictageUploader.app/" and application launch.

Comment: run whereis open in terminal

Comment: @ Parag Bafna. Its give this "-bash: run: command not found".

Comment: whereis open
/usr/bin/open

Comment: [task setLaunchPath:@"open"]; and check.