# Launch Service with Parameters

Tags: xamarin.mac

I am implementing launch service on Xamarin.Mac, I am successful in launching my application via web browser. My question is: I want to pass some parameters along with the Launch Service, How can I do so in Xamarin.Mac? Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you wanted to launch an application with arguments you'd use NSWorkspace like this:

[Launching an Mac App with Objective-C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048677/launching-an-mac-app-with-objective-c-cocoa)

```
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.LaunchApplication
```

with a dictionary of configuration options as shown.

I have no idea how to do that launching from a web browser.

You'll likely need to do something like this to read them as well:

[Xamarin Macintosh Customer URL protocol handle passed parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787480/xamarin-macintosh-customer-url-protocol-handle-passed-parameter/42836183#42836183)