# Xamarin Macintosh Customer URL protocol handle passed parameter

Tags: macos, url, arguments, protocols, xamarin.mac

I've written a Macintosh app that handles a custom protocol:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>My Cool Handler</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>coolhandler</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

All well and good. It launches. However, I'm clicking on a link like this:

coolhandler://Iwant/toparse/this

In Windows, the registry entry is simple and this work just fine. When my Windows app launches, the whole url is passed as an argument and I can parse it.

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _url = !e.Args.Any()?"":e.Args[0];
        //parse the url
    }
```

Where, in my pList or in the app do I handle this? i.e, how do I pass the url argument to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this in C# likely:

[Accessing command line arguments in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146849/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-objective-c)

Which would look something like:

```
string[] args = NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.Arguments;
```